# Highlighting numbers in the text in asp textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net

For an existing ASP.Net application, I have to highlight the numbers that user may enter as part of the text in a textbox on the aspx page. I created a function with a JQuery that I used for my MVC application and am calling that in the code behind. I have even tried creating a regex function, using html tags to change the font color and then using Html.Decode to present the output but the html tags are not rendered in the output. In both cases the app runs without any errors but the numbers are not highlighted.

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
    $(document).ready(function () { document.getElementById("#<%= Notes_TextBox1.ClientID%>").focus(); });
    function PIIHighlight() {
        var intRegex= \d+;
        ///[0-9 -()+]+$/;
       // var intRegex = /^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/;
        var values = document.getElementById("#<%= Notes_TextBox1.ClientID%>").innerHTML.split(" ");
        alert(values);
        values.forEach(function (elem, idx) {
            //$("values").each(function(){
            if (!isNaN(elem) || intRegex.test(elem)) {
                values[idx] = "<span class='highlight'>" + elem + "</span>";
                alert(elem);
            }
        });
        values = values.join(" ");
        document.getElementById("#<%= Notes_TextBox1.ClientID%>").innerHTML = values;

    }
</script>
```

The code behind the click of a button is

```
Notes_TextBox1.Focus();

if (!IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("PIIHighlight"))
{
   String PIIHighlight = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">PIIHighlight();</script>";
   RegisterStartupScript("PIIHighlight", PIIHighlight);
   return;
}
```

Is there a way I can troubleshoot to see if the script is being reached? can you please help to understand what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: What browser are you using to view the page? Most browsers have a developer console. Chrome and IE (probably Firefox as well): Press F12 and it should show you information, including whether a JS script is not running properly.

Comment: Thanks - I stepped through and it seems like its raising an error "Unable to get the value of the property 'innerHtml': object is null or undefined". Its not able to get the id of the textbox I believe. what can I do to get the correct id?

Comment: A textbox doesn't (I think?) have an innerHtml tag. I can't remember exactly -- I'm not very proficient with JS myself. Instead of "innerHtml", try just "value". `var values = document.getElementById("#<%= Notes_TextBox1.ClientID%>").value.split(" ");`